# Php range no reconce ceros a la izquierda

Tags: php

Tengo que hacer una serie numérica partiendo de un rango por ejemplo:
Inicial--> `0000050` al Final--> `0000060`

Utilizo:

```
foreach (range(0000050, 0000060) as $número) {
    echo $número.'<br>';
}
```

Lo que imprime es:
del `64...........al............104`

Se supone que debería ser `0000050`, `0000061` así hasta el `0000060`.

Agradezco su ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo preocuparte unicamente por la cifra y luego rellenar con **ceros** a la izquierda

```html
 <?php 
    $cifra = 50;
    $cantidad = 10;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $cantidad ; $i++) {
       echo  str_pad($cifra + $i, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "</br>";
    }
  ?>
```

Enlace a documentacion de la funcion [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php)

Answer (score 4):

En casi todos los lenguajes de programación (por no decir todos), se omiten los ceros a la izquierda al interpretar números, porque realmente no tienen valor. En el peor de los casos, dependiendo de la cantidad de ceros, podría interpretarlos con otra base, como octal.

Si los necesitas formateados, entonces conviértelos a cadena y agrega los ceros necesarios con [str_pad()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php)

```
foreach (range(50, 60) as $número) {
    echo str_pad($número, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '<br>';
}
```

Descripción de argumentos recibidos por la función:

- `$numero`: Cadena (o número) a rellenar
- `7`: Longitud máxima; si el dato original tiene menos de esos caracteres, se va a rellenar hasta tener esa longitud
- `'0'`: Caracter con el que se va a rellenar la cadena
- `STR_PAD_LEFT`: Agregar caracteres a la izquierda; si omites este parámetro, los caracteres se agregarán a la derecha del valor

Comment: PHP interpreta los números enteros con `0` a la izquierda como octal `echo 0050; // 40` y los `0x...` como hexadecimal. Ver [números enteros](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.integer.php)

Comment: @aeportugal, gracias por la aclaración, ya la agregué a la respuesta.